# Backup files and restore them on uninstall with InnoSetup?

Tags: inno-setup

Consider the following:

- I have two files, for example `XXX.txt` and `YYY.txt`
- I want to install them to a folder (let's say `files`), in which there are already `XXX.txt` and `YYY.txt` files
- I want to "back up" the two original files, renaming them to `XXX.txt.backup` and `YYY.txt.backup`
- On uninstall I want to restore the two files to their original state

How can I achieve this with Inno Setup?

Comment: What do you want to happen if the installer finds `XXX.txt.backup` in the folder already - skip the backup? Overwrite the old backup?

Answer (score 13):

Add

```
[Files]
; Backup Function_Template
Source: "{app}\XXX.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"; DestName: "XXX.txt.bkup"; Flags: external skipifsourcedoesntexist uninsneveruninstall
```

That would move the existing file, and the flags will prevent from uninstalling it. Now in the code you can put

```
[Code] 
procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
var
  OldFile: string;
begin
  case CurUninstallStep of    
    usPostUninstall:
      begin
        OldFile := ExpandConstant('{app}\XXX.txt.bkup');
        if FileExists(OldFile) then
          RenameFile(OldFile, ExpandConstant('{app}\XXX.txt'));
      end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Source: "{app}\XXX.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"; DestName: "XXX.txt.bkup"; Flags: external skipifsourcedoesntexist uninsneveruninstall
```

Did not appear to work, since "The compiler will prepend the path of your installation's source directory if you do not specify a fully qualified pathname."

However, I just discovered this works fine! I had left off the "external" flag.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As this isn't an answer but a follow up to another answer, can you post it as a comment instead? If the answer is wrong, you can edit it with a suitable description and it'll be approved by a more experianced user. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Well, maybe a popup saying "There is already an XXX.txt.backup. Do you really want to overwrite it?"