# Inno Setup - backup directory tree if exists & restore by uninstall

Tags: backup, inno-setup, restore

How can I backup easily all files (in all subdirectories unlimited depth) which already exists in destination directory for installation, and how can I restore all backuped files by uninstallation?

Thanks in advance.

```
[Files]
Source: "setupData\*"; DestDir: "{app}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backup: In yours `[Files]` section entry, use the `external`, `recursesubdirs`, `skipifsourcedoesntexist` and `uninsneveruninstall` flags. See [Backup files and restore them on uninstall with InnoSetup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3531599/850848)

Restore: See also the [Backup files and restore them on uninstall with InnoSetup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3531599/850848) To restore a directory tree, you will need `DirectoryCopy` function from [Inno Setup: copy folder, subfolders and files recursively in Code section](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33391915/850848).

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately the Flag combination doesn't  work for me, bud the DirectoryCopy has helped me cope.